# How can I pass a list of numba jitted functions as an argument into another numba jitted function?

Tags: python, numba, jit

This code works fine as expected

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


def f1(x):
    return 2 * x

def f2(x):
    return x - 4

def f(funcs, x):
    out = np.zeros(len(funcs))
    for i in range(len(out)):
        out[i] = funcs[i](x)
    return out

f([f1, f2], 3)
>>> array([ 6., -1.])
```

But if I decorate each function with `@nb.njit` (shown below), I get the error `TypeError: can't unbox heterogeneous list: type(CPUDispatcher(<function f1 at 0x2a10455e0>)) != type(CPUDispatcher(<function f2 at 0x2a5dedc10>))` so numba doesn't seem to recognise the types of each function.

What do I need to do to be able to pass a list of jitted functions into another jitted function to get numba to recognise it, compile and run properly?

With numba decorator (doesn't work):

```
@nb.njit
def f1(x):
    return 2 * x

@nb.njit
def f2(x):
    return x - 4

@nb.njit
def f(funcs, x):
    out = np.zeros(len(funcs))
    for i in range(len(out)):
        out[i] = funcs[i](x)
    return out
```